# Problema auto indentação ao salvar no VSCode

Tags: javascript, react, visual-studio-code, indentação

to com um problema na auto indentação do VSCode, já tentei desativar mesmo assim permanece o problema. Ao salvar um arquivo o VSCode muda automaticamente a indentação, segue a imagem de antes de salvar e de depois de salvar:
[image: Código antes de salvar]
[image: Código depois de salvar]

Comment: Cara o primeiro passo eh desativar todas as extensões que vc tenha instalado para ver se resolve...

Comment: Deu certo amigo, desabilitei todas as extensões e fui habilitando e testando uma a uma, a que estava alterando a indentação foi a JS-CSS-HTML Formatter, acredito que não soube configurá-la corretamente. Deixei desabilitada e agora está 100%, muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem problemas meu caro! Se vc me permitir posso postar como resposta? Ai vc pode marca-la e deixar a sua pergunta com uma resposta aceita, assim não fica no site como pendente de resposta etc

Comment: Pode sim amigo!!

Comment: Valei a  força Meydson, se a resposta te atender vc pode considerar marca-la com aceita no ícone ✔︎ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta ;)

Comment: claro meu amigo,  vc não sabe o quanto me ajudou, tava perdendo muito tempo analisando o código quando bugava!!! Muito obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara conversado nos comentários esse não é o comportamento padrão do `VS Code`, o que nos leva a acreditar fortemente que foi alguma `Extensão`, provavelmente alguma que tenha opções de formatação de código, que vc instalou e desconfigurou a indentação.

Pelo visto a extensão `JS-CSS-HTML Formatter` que buggou seu ambiente. Segundo a documentação dela ela usa internamente a formatação do `js-beautify`
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter

Vc pode mudar os `setting` para não mudar mais ao salvar `"onSave": false,`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em último caso vc pode simplesmente desinstalar essa extensão e instalar outra que não tenha auto-format ao salvar

Answer (score -2):

Comigo ocorreu o mesmo e era a extensão HTML CSS Support - CSS Intellisense. Desabilitei e pronto, voltou ao normal.

Answer (score -2):

Precisei desinstalar a extensão JS-CSS-HTML Formatter pra voltar a funcionar. Parece que tem bug nela. Instalei outra.